# reduction formulae question

Tags: integration

let $$I_n = \int_{\pi/2}^{x} \frac{\cos^{2n+1}t}{\sin(t)} \ dt, n \geq 0$$

show $$2(n+1)I_{n+1} = 2(n+1)I_n +\cos^{2n+2}x$$

I showed the result by considering $I_{n+1} - I_n$ but I'm wondering how could I do it using integration by parts?

Similarly for $J_n = \int_0^x \frac{\sinh^{2n+1}t}{\cosh(t)} \ dt$

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n=\int_{\pi/2}^x \frac{\cos^{2n+1}t}{\sin t}\,dt=\int_{\pi/2}^x \frac{\cos^{2n-1}t (1-\sin^2 t)}{\sin t}\,dt= I_{n-1}-\int_{\pi/2}^x \cos^{2n-1}t\sin t\,dt $$

Use the substitution $\cos t=y \Rightarrow -\sin t\,dt=dy$ to get:
$$\int_{\pi/2}^x \cos^{2n-1}t\sin t\,dt =-\int_0^{\cos x} t^{2n-1}\,dt=-\frac{\cos^{2n}x}{2n}$$
Hence,
$$I_n=I_{n-1}+\frac{\cos^{2n}x}{2n}$$
Replace $n$ with $n+1$ to get the final result.

You should be able to proceed in a similar manner for $J_n$.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm really looking at how I can use integration by parts for this.

Answer (score 0):

for $I_n$ write $$ I_n = \int_{\pi /2}^x \frac{\cos^{2n+1}t \sin(t)}{\sin^2t} \ dt$$ and let $ u = \cos^{2n+1}t \sin(t)$  $v' = cosec^2(t)$ similarly for $J_n$